# Honda city car battery drain

Tags: honda, battery-drain, city

An automatic Honda City car had it's battery drained and the reason mentioned by the owner was a bit surprising to all of us.
Mentioned ; " It was because the car was kept in the reverse gear and locked"

Could anyone pls advice whether the reasoning to the battery drain was correct?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If the owner was saying the reverse lights stayed on due to the vehicle's shifter being left in the reverse position, I'd highly suspect this reasoning. To my knowledge, the reverse lights don't stay on with the vehicle shut off (I'm assuming it was shut off). I'm not seeing as how being in this position would do as they owner suggested.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable opinion. I hope this helped in understanding more about it.

Comment: Is the car manual or automatic transmission?

Answer (score 1):

Kind of sounds like the alternator is going out or there's something grounding out or your solenoid is going out not because it was in Reverse that's kind of ridiculous sorry